# Ignore unit test in native VC++ Project

Tags: unit-testing, visual-c++, vs-unit-testing-framework

How should one use the `TEST_IGNORE()` macro in native VC++ unit test projects in Visual Studio 2015?  I'm used to using `[Ignore]` in C#, but I'm apparently missing something in VC++.

Here's what I've tried, but the `TEST_IGNORE()` macro expands out to invalid code (lots of "unexpected tokens" and "syntax error:'{'" errors...)

```
TEST_CLASS(MyTests)
{
   public:
   TEST_IGNORE()
   TEST_METHOD(TestSomething)
   {
     /*Test code is here*/
   }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out.  You have to sandwich the `TEST_IGNORE()` macro in between `BEGIN_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE(testName)` and `END_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE()`

So the above code becomes

```
TEST_CLASS(MyTests)
{
   public:
   BEGIN_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE(TestSomething)
     TEST_IGNORE()
   END_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE()
   TEST_METHOD(TestSomething)
   {
     /*Test code is here*/
   }
};
```

Comment: @Stein indeed you are correct.  I removed the extraneous argument to the `END_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE`

Comment: Fortunately, this rather big attribute block doesn't have to be right in front of the matching TEST_METHOD, it can appear anywhere in the test class.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2019#test_method_attributes